# POSIXct ignore origin parameter

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

This command in R

```
format(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00",ts="UTC"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

gives me this

```
"2016-05-30 20:15"
```

Weirdly enough this:

```
format(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00",ts="UTC","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

gives me the expected result:

```
"2016-05-31 00:15:00"
```

and a warning message because the last bracket is not correctly placed.

Why isn't my first command giving me the expected result (i.e "2016-05-31 00:15")?

Comment: Where are you living? Ie. what is *your* timezone?

Comment: Change `ts` to `tz`.

Comment: @EricLecoutr: Montreal, but I Have tried EDT with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've accidentally used `ts` instead of `tz` for the timezone argument. Normally, there wouldn't be much more to it than that, but timezones have some subtleties that can be painful (especially if, like me, you work with datetime data only intermittently and have to, from time to time, refresh your R datetime knowledge), so maybe this is worth a bit more explanation.

Check what the timezone is in each of the following examples. We'll look only at the `as.POSIXct` function, because that's where the issue is:

1. Your first example resolves to the default timezone (your local time zone), because the `ts` argument is ignored. As a result the time gets converted to your local time giving `"2016-05-30 20:15"` in your time zone (which looks like U.S. Eastern Daylight Time):

   ```
   attr(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00", ts="UTC"), "tzone")
   ```

   > ```
   > [1] ""
   > ```

The next three versions give the "expected" time (`"2016-05-31 00:15:00"`) because the timezone is set to UTC in each of these cases:

2. Same as previous example, except `tz` argument sets timezone to UTC:

   ```
   attr(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), "tzone")
   ```

   > ```
   >  [1] "UTC"
   > ```
3. In your second example, the `ts` argument is once again ignored. However, the format string is interpreted as the `tz` argument, because it is unnamed and `tz` is the next (valid) argument in the order of arguments to `as.POSIXct`. However, since it is invalid as a `tz` argument, it is interpreted as `GMT` (as noted in the help file for `as.POSIXct`):

   > A time zone specification to be used for the conversion, if one is required. System-specific (see time zones), but "" is the current time zone, and "GMT" is UTC (Universal Time, Coordinated). Invalid values are most commonly treated as UTC, on some platforms with a warning.

   In other words, this time the timezone got set to UTC by accident.

   ```
   attr(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00", ts="UTC","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "tzone")
   ```

   > ```
   > [1] "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
   > ```

   But notice that if we name the argument as a `format` statement, the timezone goes back to being resolved as your local timezone rather than GMT (resulting in the time value being converted to your local time again):

   ```
   attr(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00", ts="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "tzone")
   ```

   > ```
   > [1] ""
   > ```
4. Same as previous, except we change `ts` to `tz`:

   ```
   attr(as.POSIXct(15*60,origin="2016-05-31 00:00:00", tz="UTC","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "tzone")
   ```

   > ```
   > [1] "UTC"
   > ```